# The meaning of "company" in "Pooh and company"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "company" in "[Pooh and company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Acre_Wood)"? Does it refer to Pooh's friends? But in that case shouldn't it be Pooh and the company? Thank you!

Comment: See ["Stalky & Co." (1899)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalky_%26_Co.) by Rudyard Kipling. I've never read it, but I have the impression Stalky is a bit of a bully, and the "& Co." refers to his sycophantic mates (juvenile "henchmen"). Be aware that the Pooh Bear usage is a bit of an outlier - it's usually a fairly derogatory reference, particularly in the *abbreviated* form (i.e. - ***X & Co.*** tends to imply *X and his **cronies*** rather than *X and his **friends***). So you might want to be careful about how you use it.

Comment: In the case of some Wikipedia copywriter's "metaphoric" reference to *Winnie the Pooh **and company***, the "derogatory" overtones of the usage are presumably intended to imply that Pooh is "a bit of a scamp", who "gets up to mischief". Which is typical of many children's "heroes" (Bart Simpson, Just William, Dennis the Menace, etc.). Bit it's not really a very good fit here, because so far as I recall, Pooh would never contemplate doing anything remotely "naughty" (though he does get into various "scrapes").

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I understand it as meaning 'and his usual associates' without any particularly derogatory sense.

Comment: If it's *the* company, then which established company should we assume it to be?  The Fellowship of the Ring?  Microsoft?  The uncountable indefinite sense of the word (which is the same as in *having company over for dinner*) is a better fit for the given context.

Comment: @KateBunting: Well, I freely admitted I never read *Stalky & Co.*, so I might even be mistaken about the negative associations being present there. But I can hardly be mistaken about the fact that *I personally* would normally assume either "actual" negative associations, or at least a slightly facetious nod towards mischievous scamps as opposed to well-behaved children (and animated stuffed toy animals). As acknowledged above, not everyone will feel the same. But I could *potentially* get the "wrong" message from a learner who ignored my warning, even if you would have no such problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - although 'and company', strictly speaking, does not have an automatic  or default derogatory implication, I can think of lots of situations where it is used in that way, e.g. 'that's what you'd expect from Nigel Farage and company'. Compare with 'and the usual suspects'. I sometimes see _et al._ used in this way, but I would be wary of doing that because it just means 'and others'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yes - to my mind, *the usual suspects* (or something like ***and his gang / lot / bunch***) is very often the implication of attaching metaphoric "& Co." to an ***individual*** to mean "associates" rather than a commercial organisation. Not always, but often enough that at least *some* people might get the wrong impression from a "misuse" of the form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it annoys me when I see 'of that ilk' used to mean 'and people like him or her', often with a derogatory or disparaging intent. I know some dictionaries allow the meaning of 'people similar to the person just mentioned' but I still think of it in the Scottish sense of 'of that clan'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Until just now I never even knew the "literal" meaning of ***ilk***, so that one's never bothered me. But to my mind, ***X and his ilk*** is even more likely to be derogatory than ***X & Co.***. I certainly can't imagine ***You and your ilk*** being used in an *approving* context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - personally I would spell 'co' and 'company'  with a small c if they were not part of a proper name, e.g. I detest Nigel Gove and company, but I bank with Coutts and Company.

Comment: I take it that's a Freudian slip, and that you're just lumping Nigel Farage and Michael Gove into "the same" political bucket. But to be honest, apart from the fact that they both happened to agree with half the country as regards Brexit, I can't see they have that much in common politically.

Answer (score 8):

It means 'Pooh and his friends'. You would not use 'the' before 'company'.

> You can say 'and company' after mentioning a person's name, to refer
> also to the people who are associated with that person.

[Definition of 'and company' (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/and-company)

Comment: I think it worth noting that "and the company" would imply that the person is someone authorized to speak for and/or act on behalf of an actual incorporated entity, and would probably be used to talk about some action that they're taking - "responding to allegations of wrongdoing at X Inc., CEO John Smith and the company put out a joint statement...".